# Bounding a value of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function such that $|f(z)+4| \leq | z^2 + 2 |$ for $|z|=1$

It is asked to prove that $2 \leq  |f(0)| \leq 6$

Truth is I'm not sure if it is true :

First, using the mean formula we have $|f(0) + 4| \leq \dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |f(\exp(it) + 2| dt \leq \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |\exp(2it) + 2 | dt \sim 2.12 $

I want somehow to bound $|f(0) + 4|$ by $2$ but I can't because $|z^2+2|$ is not holomorphic

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I expect that $f$ is holomorphic on the unit disc and continuous at least on the circle for the problem to make sense.

Let $g(z)=\frac{f(z)+4}{z^2+2}, |z| \le 1$. Clearly $g$ is analytic on the unit disc and continous on the boundary, and by hypothesis $|g(z)| \le 1$ on the unit circle, so by maximum modulus that holds inside the unit disc so $|g(0)| \le 1$ which translates as $|f(0)+4| \le 2$; this implies the required result by the triangle inequality